# Make for loop in Node.js wait before iterating

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, wait

**Update** Just to be clear I'm looking for a way to 'wait' or 'sleep' before iterating through the while loop. Sorry for confusion.

I have a for loop and I wanting to know what the best way to have Node.js wait before looping through each value. At the moment it just runs everything without waiting or progressing through the loop (which is the nature of Node.js) but any tips will be helpful!

```
// Loop through time period and populate database with sensor events
var startTime = moment().startOf('year').unix();
var endTime = startTime + (24*60*60)*7;
var item = {};
while ( startTime <= endTime ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < chance.natural({ min: 1, max: SENSOR_LIMIT}); i++ ) {
  //sensors.forEach(function(item) {
    item = {
      id: sensors[i]['id'],
      address: sensors[i]['address'],
      geolocation: { 
        lng: sensors[i]['geolocation']['lng'], 
        lat: sensors[i]['geolocation']['lat'] 
      },
      type: SENSOR_EVENT_TYPE,
      value: generator.generateRandomSensorEventValue(startTime),
      created_at: new Date(moment.unix(startTime).toISOString())
    }; 
    event.save(item);
  }
  // Increment time based on interval
  startTime = startTime + SENSOR_EVENT_INTERVAL;
}
```

I have added my event.save(item) snippet below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var event = require('../models/event.js').event;
var recentEvent = require('../models/recentEvent.js').recentEvent;

// Create event
exports.save = function(data) {
  var item = new event(data);
  item.create(function (error, data) {
    if (error)
      console.log('*** Could not add record');
    else
      console.log('+++ Added record to the collection');
      var item = recentEvent(data);
      item.save(function (error, data) {
        if (error)
          console.log('*** Could not add record');
        else
          console.log('+++ Added record to the capped collection');
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Wait for what exactly ?

Comment: Wait for a set period of time or until event.save(item) has completed.

Comment: And does `event.save` have a callback ?

Comment: I have added my event.save script to the original post. Should I add a call back in there? And if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using experimental ECMAScript Harmony features, you may achieve your desired behaviour using the [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) keyword.

Or, if you are OK using 3rd party libraries, I recommend to use [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async), particularly [series](https://github.com/caolan/async#series).

Alternatively, you could refactor the whole code so that instead of `for` loops it uses some callback mechanism that will advance your code to the next item to be worked on. This might be quite hard so a 3rd party library is recommended for production use unless you are interested to code this yourself for educational purposes.

Comment: Hi Robert, I have looked at async or series but struggle to implement this against my code base. Could you provide an example?

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? What have you tried so far? There ought to be some examples on the web, too... If still having trouble, I think it would justify a new question on SO.

Comment: Hi Robert. I'm looking more to delay the loop, as in mimic a delay in data being sent. Would async help with this?